# How can I validated read-only field into data model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

In my grid , there is a column which sums up the rest of columns and that column is named as Total Funds ,and it has read-only property. it is not mapped to database.
I am using C# with MVC and I wanted to give a validation using attribute in which it shouldn't allow the total to be zero.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if it does equal zero?

Comment: It should give a soft validation message Saying it can't be Zero

Answer (score 0):

I would implement OnRowDataBound method on the server. Do the check on the cell that is under the column and if the value is equal to 0 then throw your validation message here. You could even highlight the cell as red or something to signal to the user the data can't be 0.

This is assuming you already have calculated the Total Funds before data binding to the grid view.